# C# System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft JSON properties marking for serialization control by attributes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, attributes, deserialization

I am just wonder if I can mark certain property of class instance via any attribute and during serialization serialize just those marked properties (and of-course by deserializing affect also only marked properties via attribute vice-versa in instance of the class - the rest of properties should remain same...).

I know how to identify those properties by reflection, but I do not want to make another Json serialization by myself.

```
[MyFirstAttribute]
public string A { get; set; } = "hi";

[MyFirstAttribute]
public int B { get; set; } = 13;

[MySecondAttribute]
public string C { get; set; } = "something";
```

Comment: I think this is what you want: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it documented here in [this link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) you can create a custom `CustomJsonConverter` by inheriting from `JsonConverter` class.

And then use it like:

```
Employee employee = new Employee
{
    FirstName = "James",
    LastName = "Newton-King",
    Roles = new List<string>
    {
        "Admin"
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, Formatting.Indented, new KeysJsonConverter(typeof(Employee)));

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ArgeKumandan advice:

```
public class KeysJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;
    public KeysJsonConverter(params Type[] types) => _types = types;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object) t.WriteTo(writer);
        else
        {
            JObject jo = new JObject();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in value.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!prop.CanRead) continue;
                object propVal = prop.GetValue(value, null);
                if (propVal is null || !Attribute.IsDefined(prop, _types[0])) continue;
                    jo.Add(prop.Name, JToken.FromObject(propVal, serializer));
            }
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get => false; }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => _types.Any(t => t == _types[0]);
}
```

and then usage:

```
// serialization
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectInstance1, Formatting.Indented, new KeysJsonConverter(typeof(MyFirstAttribute)));

// deserialization to an existing instance that updates just the properties contained in JSON
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonCommon, objectInstance2);
```